# Checking if a package is installed specifically via pip

Tags: python, pip

Checking if a particular package is available from within Python can be done via

```
try:
    import requests
except ImportError:
    available = False
else: 
    available = True
```

Additionally, I would like to know if the respective package has been **installed with `pip`** (and can hence been updated with `pip install -U package_name`).

Any hints?

Comment: in the code ? otherwise u can check with `pip list`

Comment: It needs to be in code. If necessary, parsing the output of `subprocess` could be it.

Comment: @JodhSingh This is about whether a package is installed _with pip_. Perhaps you have a suggestion on how to improve the wording?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the linked question.  The linked one is about finding out if a package is installed.  This one is specifically about finding out if it is installed *with pip*.

Comment: Agreed, not a duplicate. I believe it can be solved with something like that: `import pkg_resources; pkg_resources.get_distribution('requests').get_metadata('INSTALLER')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe one way to figure out if a project has been installed by *pip* is by looking at the content of the `INSTALLER` text file in the distribution's `dist-info` directory for this project. With `pkg_resources` from *setuptools* this can be done programmatically like the following (*error checking omitted*):

```
import pkg_resources

pkg_resources.get_distribution('requests').get_metadata('INSTALLER')
```

This would return `pip\n`, in case `requests` was indeed installed by *pip*.

Comment: Well, this works if it is indeed installed via pip. It fails with `FileNotFound` for Debian-installed packages because, e.g., `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests-2.22.0.egg-info/INSTALLER` is not installed there. That's good enough for me.

Comment: Yes, this should be rewritten with the proper checks and/or try clauses in place.

Answer (score 0):

You said `subprocess.call()` is allowed, so

```
available = not(subprocess.call(["pip", "show", "requests"]))
```

Comment: Gives `False` for me although `requests` is installed with pip.

Comment: I forgot a `not()`... `retval = 0` means `success`, but casts to `False`. `retval != 0` means `failed` but casts to `True` :-)